# Discord Bot with multiple if/else role permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, discord, bots

I have a bot that works and one of the commands of the bot is (for this post I've replaced Role IDs with names):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'youtube',
    description: "Sends a Youtube Link",
    execute(message, args){

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('DJRankID')){
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');

        } else {message.channel.send('Sorry, you dont seem to have DJ Permissions');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add assigning the DJ role if they already have another specific role:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: "Sends a Youtube Link",
    execute(message, args){

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('DJRoleID')){
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');

        } else if(message.member.roles.cache.has('MemberRoleID')){
            message.member.roles.add('DJRoleID');
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');

        } else if(message.member.roles.cache.has('OfficerRoleID')){
            message.member.roles.add('DJRoleID');
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');
        
        } else if(message.member.roles.cache.has('LeaderRoleID')){
            message.member.roles.add('DJRoleID');
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');

        } else if(message.member.roles.cache.has('HelperRoleID')){
            message.member.roles.add('DJRoleID');
            message.channel.send('https://www.youtube.com');

        } else {message.channel.send('Sorry, you dont seem to have DJ Permissions');
        }
    }
}
```

Youtube command works fine but the Play command does nothing. Bot has Manage Roles enabled. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the code look like where you are calling the object?

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand the question. The rest of the bot works it's only this play command that doesn't

Comment: Your main file where you are including all those files.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, the error was in main.js. I had  `var handlers = ['command_handler', 'event_handler']` instead of `var handlers = ['command_handler.js', 'event_handler.js']`

Comment: So you solved the problem?

Comment: Yup thank you! I was convinced it was in this file not the other

Comment: Great. Happy coding!